# Cannot Add Functions to Unity Events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot add a method to my unity events. What is causing this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNADS.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EventTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
     public void TestingStuff() {

    }
```

this is the script with the function

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
public class MyEventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent myEvent;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

this is the script with the event

I tried making different scripts and different functions but that didn't work.

Comment: how are you dding things to it? your test event script is empty

Comment: What do you mean by "dding", can you clarify?

Comment: Adding. It was the word adding

Comment: I was trying to add the method with the unity inspector, however the unity inspector won't let me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't have the correct .NET framework. This somehow caused unity events to not work correctly.